# click category name to show all sub category products in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

How do I do this -> Click category name to show all sub category products in opencart. See this [**link**](http://www.dddesignsindia.com/demo/). When I click Lehenga it shows some products. But, When I click Sarees or Salwar kameez it shows empty page.

But In my localhost When I access Sarees Category link it shows some product lists. This site was developed by another developer. And I'm also new to opencart. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue from opencart forum [answer](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=80251)

Go to `catalog/controller/product/category.php`

Find `'filter_category_id' => $category_id,` and add this line `'filter_sub_category' => true,` .  Now it shows the all subcategory products when you access category name. I hope this answer will help anyone here..